# How to find an array object according to given information?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array in AngularJS controller like this:

```
$scope.persons = [{name:'Joey', age:'27'},{name:'Lucy', age:'22'}]
```

I have got a name 'Lucy', how can I get the age of the name in the controller (not in HTML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a plunk here that outlines a single result, with just the age, as well as multiple results.

This could also be implemented within a filter, which is documented on the Angular site here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

https://plnkr.co/edit/OFRMzpQrZfTOnaFyJP7Z?p=info

```
angular.module('plnk',[]).controller('plnkCtrl', function($scope){

  // Note, I added a second Joey here to test the multiple function.
  // For output, check the browser console.

  $scope.persons = [{name:'Joey', age:'27'},{name:'Joey', age:'28'},{name:'Lucy', age:'22'}]

  console.log('Single -> ', getAgeSingle('Lucy'));
  console.log('Multiple ->',getAgeMultiple('Joey'));

  function getAgeMultiple(personLookup) {

    var results = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.persons,function(person){
       if (person.name === personLookup) {
         results.push(person);
         // or results.push(person.age) for age only
       }
     });
    return results;

  }

  function getAgeSingle(personLookup) {
    var result = '';
    angular.forEach($scope.persons,function(person){
       if (person.name === personLookup && !result) {
         result = person.age;
       }
     });
    return result;
  }

});
```

Comment: I like this because it accounts for multiple people with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to loop through the scope:

```
$scope.persons = [{name:'Joey', age:'27'}, {name:'Lucy', age:'22'}]

function getAge(name) {
    angular.forEach($scope.persons, function (value, index) {
        if (value.name === name) {
            return parseInt(value.age, 10);
        }
    });
    return undefined;
}
```

The HTML way:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <td>Name: {{person.name}} Age: {{person.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [{name:'Joey', age:'27'}, {name:'Lucy', age:'22'}];
});
```

Comment: This doesn't do any filtering as per OP question. OP also said they want to retrieve in controller..not html

Comment: @charlietfl Updated to include filter.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the array and check, like this:

```
function getAge(name)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++)
  {
     var person = $scope.persons[i];
     if (person.name === name)
     {
        return parseInt(person.age, 10);
     }
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

This has a couple caveats -- if you have dupes you'll only get the first one and it runs in linear time.  If you control the data source it'd be better to use a JS object/hashmap/dictionary/whatever you want to call it.